# Redux-form, Invalid prop 'value' of type 'number' supplied to 'TextInput', expected 'string'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux-form, react-proptypes

I am using a custom component in a redux-form field as follows.

```
<Field name="height" parse={value => Number(value)} component={NumberInput} />
```

The custom component uses React Native's **TextInput** component and it looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { View, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { COLOR_PRIMARY } from '../constants';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  inputStyle: {
    height: 30,
    width: 50,
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderColor: COLOR_PRIMARY,
    borderWidth: 2,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  errorStyle: {
    color: COLOR_PRIMARY,
  },
});

const NumberInput = (props) => {
  const { input: { value, onChange }, meta: { touched, error } } = props;
  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput
        keyboardType="numeric"
        returnKeyType="go"
        maxLength={3}
        style={styles.inputStyle}
        value={value}
        onChangeText={onChange}
      />
      {touched &&
        (error && (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.errorStyle}>{error}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
    </View>
  );
};

NumberInput.propTypes = {
  meta: PropTypes.shape({
    touched: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    error: PropTypes.string,
  }).isRequired,
  input: PropTypes.shape({
    // value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
    onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
};

export default NumberInput;
```

I want to store the the value entered for the height field as a Number and not a String type. Hence I am using parse to convert String to a Number as you can see in the Field.

I am able to do this but keep getting the Yellow Box warning of:

```
 Invalid prop 'value' of type 'number' supplied to 'TextInput', expected 'string'
```

*Have tried setting the value PropType to any, string, number, or oneOfType string or number, nothing seems to work. Have also tried setting type="number" in the Field and TextInput, as well as type="text".*

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Basically, in your props you are passing numerical value of value.You have to passed it in the form of string.You can edit your code like this:

```
<TextInput
  keyboardType="numeric"
  returnKeyType="go"
  maxLength={3}
  style={styles.inputStyle}
  value={`${value}`} //here
  onChangeText={onChange}
/>
```

Comment: I would imagine that it would be more performant to use value={String(value)} rather than value={`${value}`} since the template version will require a parser to extract the variable names and map to strings instead of casting to a string directly.

Answer (score 15):

This way should be cleaner:

```
<TextInput
  value={yourValue ? String(yourValue) : null}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say this will be much cleaner.

```
<TextInput
  value={yourValue && String(yourValue)}
  ...
/>
```